# ubuntu copy files from windows to /var/www risks

Tags: security, ubuntu, copy, paste

I have a windows machine for development. When code is working I ssh and copy files from developmnet to production which is /var/www.

Is this copy and paste safe? I see that some files are marked for read/write and some others only for read. Should I be concerned when transfering files from dev to prod this way?

What should be the output of the files when I do >ls /var/www?

If somebody can give some hints. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

/var/www/ is the default documentroot and as such should / would have root folders of your web sites. ls would list them out while ls -ltr would give you all the property info on those folders / files.

You can ssh into Dev and transfer files to prod, but a better way would be to setup secure ftp and a specific user account that only has access to specific directories under var/www/ and then you button it up to all others. That way only one user has access to Prod at the filesystem level and it is very limited access and logged.

Comment: at install when i ls -ltr in /var/www i see all the files belong to root. After I copy/transfer files I see the owner of the files transfer belong to a diferent user. Is this unsafe? Should I change this files owner's to root?

Comment: it really depends on the level of authorization the specific user has. But yes, if you were being audited then what you describe would be an issue.

Comment: If you designed that user security to only access the specific directories required then I would say you did due diligence. However, judging from your question I might say otherwise.